# Значение слова «Притаращился»

Tags: значение-слов

Это — пришёл или присмотрелся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно Словарю русских народных говоров (СПб, "Наука", 1998, вып. 32, с. 10), это диалектный (Сибирь) вариант слова **притащился** (добрался с трудом). Другое значение - **пришёл без приглашения** (Зауралье).

https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/32.pdf